# Is invoke or ienumerator a better method in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I sometimes use Invoke and sometimes ienumerator when I want the code to run after a certain wait. but which is a more robust and optimized method? I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation of Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) states:

> If you need to pass parameters to your method, consider using Coroutine instead. Coroutines also provide better performance.

Comment: Another thing is that coroutines can have variable delay times, while invoke (repeating, specifically) only has the one, and must be cancelled when changing the delay.